# Android: Getting average sensor value

Tags: android, sensors, average

I'm trying to store the average light level (using the light sensor) from the past few seconds to use in a comparison to call another function if the current light level is about 25% of the average.

My problem is I'm not entirely sure how to go about storing the average.

I'm assuming you would do something along the lines of

```
while(sensorUpdateTime + sampleTime < CurrentTime)
   average += currentValue / updatesSampleRate;
```

I'm just kind of at a loss on how to store the average.

Answer (score 1):

If you sample rate is quite constant,  you can store  values in an array  and do "circular" updates  ( use array[sampleNumber % array.length] to  find  oldest value to expunge.

Then you just substract expunged value out of kept sum,   and  add new value.

This way you have average over past  array.length sensor readings.   And you can also get  variance -  just keep sum of squarer sensor  values, and then:

sigma = sqr(  MX2 - MX )

Comment: I was toying around with it more last night and I found that I can create a Chronometer and use that to tick every second.

However I also thought that since the sensor only needs to be on for a short period of time, I don't really NEED the average, just set the value to whatever when I initially turn everything on.

Comment: After reading this comment I do not understand what you really want

Answer (score 0):

The average is just a particular case of the low pass filter. It will introduce a delay but if there is no problem you can use it. You have [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-pass_filter#Algorithmic_implementation) a pseudo-code for a low pass filter implementation. You just modify the `alfa` parameter. You can apply this for the last N values.